# Properties of Field Automorphisms

Tags: field-theory

The following statement is supposed t be false.

Let $K$ be a field and let $\sigma ,\Gamma \in Aut(K)$ be two distinct field automorphisms of $K$. Then there exists $\alpha, \beta \in K$ not both zero such that $\alpha\sigma(x)+\beta\Gamma(x)=0$  for all $x\in K$.

Can someone give me an example as to why the above statement is False ?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ with the identity and the complex conjugation?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying in $x=1$ results in $\alpha=-\beta$. In other words, $\sigma=\Gamma$ is a necessary condition for such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to exist.

Comment: In other words, not only is the statement false in general, but it is actually always false.